# Getting the difference iterated over every row from one dataframe to another in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, diff

I have two datasets: df1 and df2, each with a column named 'value' with 10 records. Currently I have:

`df = df1.value -  df2.value`

but this code outputs 10 rows only (as expected). How would one iterate the difference for all rows instead of just the difference between corresponding row index (and get a table of 100 records instead)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how = 'cross'` (cartesian product), then get the columns difference with [`pandas.DataFrame.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html):

```
#setup
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"value":[7,5,4,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"value":[1,7,9,5,3]})

df2.merge(df1, "cross", suffixes=['x','']).diff(axis = 1).dropna(1)
```

**Output**

```
   value
0       6
1       4
2       3
3       7
4       8
5       0
6      -2
7      -3
8       1
9       2
10     -2
11     -4
12     -5
13     -1
14      0
15      2
16      0
17     -1
18      3
19      4
20      4
21      2
22      1
23      5
24      6
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, it seems that I I keep getting a `KeyError: 'cross'` error. I've tried your example as is and the issue persists. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: You're using an old version of pandas, `how = 'cross'` was released a few months ago

Comment: Ah yes that was indeed the problem. ty

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ndf = df.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1),on='key',suffixes=('_l','_r')).drop('key',axis=1)

ndf['value_l'] - ndf['value_r']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `outer` subtraction.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"value":[7,5,4,8,9]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"value":[1,7,9,5,3]})

np.subtract.outer(df1['value'].to_numpy(), df2['value'].to_numpy())
#array([[ 6,  0, -2,  2,  4],
#       [ 4, -2, -4,  0,  2],
#       [ 3, -3, -5, -1,  1],
#       [ 7,  1, -1,  3,  5],
#       [ 8,  2,  0,  4,  6]])
```

---

Add a `.ravel()` if you want the same order as a cross join.

```
np.subtract.outer(df1['value'].to_numpy(), df2['value'].to_numpy()).ravel('F')

#array([ 6,  4,  3,  7,  8,  0, -2, -3,  1,  2, -2, -4, -5, -1,  0,  2,  0,
#       -1,  3,  4,  4,  2,  1,  5,  6])
```